# Parsing an array of JSON objects in Logstash

Tags: json, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have a log file that's an array of objects that looks something like this:

```
[
  { "cate1": "data1a", "cate2": "data2a" },
  { "cate1": "data1b", "cate2": "data2b" },
  { "cate1": "data1c", "cate2": "data2c" }
]
```

and I need each object in the array to be a separate entry in Elasticsearch and each "cate" to be a field. My current logstash.conf file is:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
  }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "event"
  }
  mutate {
    gsub => ["message","\]",""]
    gsub => ["message","\[",""]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
  }
}
```

but it tags each line with "_jsonparsefailure" except the first entry and it parses the square brackets as well. How would I go about configuring Logstash to do this properly?

Comment: Please show us what the output looks like, as well as what your config/output were when you tried the json codec

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `json` filter, you should look into using the [`json` codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json.html) on your input. It seems to do exactly what you want:

> This codec may be used to decode (via inputs) and encode (via outputs)
>   full JSON messages. If the data being sent is a JSON array at its root
>   multiple events will be created (one per element).

It would look something like this:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    codec => json{ }
  }
}
```